# XSD: What does the "name" attribute mean for the "anyAttribute" element?

Tags: xml, xsd, bpmn

I am currently reading the specification for [BPMN 2.0](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/PDF). In this specification, definitions for the parts of BPMN are given as XML schemas.

In one of those schemas (Table 8.3, p. 54), I stumbled upon a line that does not make sense to me:

```
<xsd:element name="definitions" type="tDefinitions"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="tDefinitions">
  ...
    <xsd:anyAttribute name="exporter" type="xsd:ID"/>
  ...
```

What puzzles me is the use of the "name" attribute in conjunction with the "xsd:anyAttribute" element. If I understood the element's [definition](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_anyattribute.asp) correctly, its purpose is to allow using "unknown" attributes that are not specified by the schema. So what could be the purpose of restricting "xsd:anyAttribute" to the concrete name "exporter" instead of just directly specifying an (optional) attribute with that name?

Comment: Double check the actual schema files. It may be a mistake in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is likely just a mistake in the documentation and they indented to declare an attribute using `xsd:attribute`.**

[`xsd:anyAttribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#element-anyAttribute) does not have an `@name`.

```
<anyAttribute
  id = ID
  namespace = ((##any | ##other) | List of (anyURI | (##targetNamespace | ##local)) )  : ##any
  processContents = (lax | skip | strict) : strict
  {any attributes with non-schema namespace . . .}>
  Content: (annotation?)
</anyAttribute>
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! That was my impression too, but I was not sure whether it is just a matter of me having insufficient XSD understanding. ;-)

Comment: Just discovered that the [XML Schemas](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100501/BPMN20.xsd) given on the OMG website actually use `xsd:attribute` instead of `xsd:anyAttribute`! So @Mads, you were perfectly right, it is a mistake in the specification document.

Comment: Cool.  You should send a note to the publishers to alert them of the mistake, so that they can fix it and publish corrected documentation.

Comment: Good suggestion! I reported the mistake to the OMG.

Comment: anyAttribute is not working, please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14872678/306488

Answer (score 0):

The anyAttribute element enables the author to extend the XML document with attributes not specified by the schema.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_anyattribute.asp

Here will be everything you need to know! You have to see this anyAttribute like a wildcard.

Comment: As written in my question, I read this definition of "anyAttribute", and I was confused because it does not specify a "name" attribute for the element.

Comment: Yes it gives your XML space to have any attribute, like i told you you can use it as a wildcard. So attribute X or Y it doesn't matter!