# Allow variable element attributes in xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd

How would the element complexType look like if I want it to have variable attribute names,  count and values ?

```
<mtd:attributes icon="remove" security="D" variable1="F" variable2="D"/>
```

I tried :

```
        <xsd:element name="attributes">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:anyAttribute/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
```

but it doesn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `processContents=skip`

Comment: Where ? To anyAttribute ? It accepts only id, namespace and processContents attributes

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it with :

```
<xsd:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
```